# Python - chaining generators with input parameters

Tags: python, generator

I have to execute generator function multiple times and chain results. The problem is this function has input object parameter which is different for each run. A the end, when I loop for results unfortunately this param is the same in every result. I think this code will make it more clear:

```
import itertools

class Data:
  def __init__(self, constant, fruit=None, color=None):
    self.constant = constant
    self.fruit = fruit
    self.color = color

def get_generator(data):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        yield [i, data]

def for_colors(data):
  colors = ['blue', 'red']
  result = iter(())

  for color in colors:
    data.color = color
    result = itertools.chain(result, get_generator(data))

  return result


def for_friuts(data):
  fruits = ['apple', 'orange']
  result = iter(())

  for fruit in fruits:
    data.fruit = fruit
    result = itertools.chain(result, for_colors(data))
  
  return result


def run():
  data = Data('constant')
  return for_friuts(data)

for item in run():
  print(f'{item[0]} {item[1].constant} {item[1].fruit} {item[1].color}')
```

What is returned:

```sh
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange red
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange red
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange red
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange red
```

What is expected:

```sh
1 constant apple red
2 constant apple blue
1 constant apple red
2 constant apple blue
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange blue
1 constant orange red
2 constant orange blue
```

In result there is the same Data object reference in every item.
I'd like to fix it somehow without changing code structure (keep hierarchical calling etc.)

Comment: Because you are passing the exact same object every time: `for_colors(data)`. Create a new object.

Comment: Also using chain like this isn't great. Just make your function a generator.